# (c++) templates with functions and vectors

Tags: c++, templates, vector

The following code is failing to run. From my attempts to debug it, I'm guessing I have some misunderstanding about how to use templates with functions and vectors.

```
template<typename T>
T minT(std::vector<T> data){
    T min = data[0];
    for(int i=0; i< data.size(); i++){
        if(data[i] < min){
            min =data[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}


template<typename T>
void Hist(std::vector<T> data, T increment){
    T max = maxT<T>(data);
    T min = minT<T>(data);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<int> v;

   Hist(v,2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `v` is empty, so `data[0]` is illegal.

Comment: How about using [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element)
 and [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)?

Comment: You ought to have tested `minT` before you tried to build `Hist` on it.

Comment: @Henri, that's fair, but I want to learn what the issue is.

Comment: maxT is not defined.

Comment: When you say `'fails to run'`, what exactly is the problem? Is it a crash and if so did you try running under debugger to find the crash location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are:

- **You didn't define a `maxT` function.**
- **The `std::vector` does not have a [0] element because it was never given values to construct itself with or append onto itself.**

Once I fixed these two problems, the code appears to work. `<vector>` and `<iostream>` have been added for convenience and correctness.

**[See it live on Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3801d65ff385e06)**